# jQuery post POST became GET

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Strange situation

i send date with jQuery post

```
$.post('/headline/', {date : 'some content'});
```

But server header show that request is GET instead POST.

Local version works fine, but when upload to server then POST became GET

Other post requests works fine, just this one not working

P.s. backed is Laravel

Comment: Did you set up the routes correctly? Please post all ur routes.

Comment: Route::post('headline', 'HeadlineController@create');

Route is correct, because everything runs on homestead right, just on server is problem

Comment: Can you try to remove the trailing slash on server side? This is just on a whim though

Comment: Thank that works

Comment: Please close this question. I will add my comment as the answer, please select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to remove the trailing slash on server side? This is just on a whim though